# Open Policy Agent reduce array when element in array

Tags: open-policy-agent

I have been trying to achieve something with Open Policy Agent that I am sure should be possible. Just struggling with the on-ramp to the Rego language (I think). I am using the playground to get a feel for how to achieve the following.

I have the following data input.

```json
{
    "tags": [
        {
            "key": "test"
        },
        {
            "key": "test2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Rego code

```
package play
minimum_tags = {"test","test2"}
deny[msg] {
    tags := input.tags[_][key]
    # At this point I have an array and a set. I can convert the minimum_tags to Array
    # But I can't really figure out how to do an iteration to check each tags value is in minimum_tags. Or reduce the minimum tags until its empty
}
```

I can only see the ability to reduce a set using the `a1 - a2` built in. Doesn't seem to be a way to effect change on an Array

Answer (score 1):

I think the idiomatic approach would be to convert `tags` to a set as well, so that you can use set operations (like you suggest) to check that all tags from `minimum_tags` are included in `tags`:

```
deny[msg] {
    tags := {tag | tag := input.tags[_].key}
    missing_tags := minimum_tags - tags
    count(missing_tags) > 0
    
    msg := sprintf("Missing tags: %v", [concat(", ", missing_tags)])
}
```

If you *really* want to have `tags` as an array, you could do something like this:

```
deny[msg] {
    tags := [tag | tag := input.tags[_].key]
    
    required_tag := minimum_tags[_]
    
    not in_array(required_tag, tags)
    
    msg := sprintf("Missing tag: %v", [required_tag])
}

in_array(item, arr) {
    item == arr[_]
}
```

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks a bunch for taking the time to answer. Is there some equivalent of `val := tag[key]` for multiple objects to un-marshal key, vals?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. Perhaps we could continue the discussion on the OPA Slack? https://slack.openpolicyagent.org/